# All Python Permutations and Combinations of Pinyin (Mandarin Romanization)

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, pinyin

I'm looking to make a list of toneless pinyin combinations/permutations.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('chinese_tones.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
data.columns = ["pinyin", "character"]
data['pinyin'] = data['pinyin'].str.replace('\d+', '')
```

The current format of the data is:

```
| pinyin| character|
|------|----|---|---|---|
| cang | 仓 |   |   |   |
| cang | 藏 |   |   |   |
| cao  | 操 |   |   |   |
| cao  | 曹 |   |   |   |
| cao  | 草 |   |   |   |
```

The expected result would be a list like:

```
cangcang
cangcao
caocang
caocao
```

I can dedupe the list and clean myself. I'm just trying to include every combination in every order of two pinyin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `drop_duplicates`, and then use an `outer` addition to get all combinations.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = df['pinyin'].drop_duplicates().to_numpy()
pd.Series(np.add.outer(s, s).ravel())

#0    cangcang
#1     cangcao
#2     caocang
#3      caocao
#dtype: object

If you want to add back the original words just add `s` back to this outer addition.

pd.Series(s.tolist() + np.add.outer(s, s).ravel().tolist())
#0        cang
#1         cao
#2    cangcang
#3     cangcao
#4     caocang
#5      caocao
#dtype: object
```

---

If you want to have the individual words also then we can accomplish a similar thing with a merge, instead of dropping down to numpy. `drop_duplicates` again and assign a temporary key to accomplish the entire merge, then add the strings.

```
s = df[['pinyin']].drop_duplicates().assign(key=1)
res = s.merge(s, on='key').drop(columns='key')
res['combined'] = res['pinyin_x'] + res['pinyin_y']

#  pinyin_x pinyin_y  combined
#0     cang     cang  cangcang
#1     cang      cao   cangcao
#2      cao     cang   caocang
#3      cao      cao    caocao
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. If there any way to include the individual components as well (i.e. cang and cao) in the new series?

Comment: thanks for the update. I was thinking one series or list for all of them. So "cang, cao, cangcao, caocang, etc..." Does that make sense?

Comment: @Alex oh I see, does that new addition solve your problem?